# Earth surface acceleration and inertial geodesics

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, acceleration, planets, geodesics

I hope this is an appropriate question for this forum.  It is one I have struggled with for a while.

I read that in GR gravity is not a force, and that the apparent force we feel and can measure (eg with a free body test or accelerometer) standing on the Earth’s surface is a consequence of the surface’s outward acceleration.

I also read that free falling objects in deep space are on constant speed, inertial geodesics.  Under the influence of a large mass, like the Earth, then inertial geodesics curve towards it.  An object that is close enough to the Earth will move towards it, still on an inertial path, so will not measure itself as undergoing any acceleration.

I have learnt to be content with both of these concepts (as concepts, not with a deep mathematical understanding) in most cases.  For example, if I step off a high building on Earth, I would be on an inertial geodesic that curves towards the centre of the planet, so would be weightless and not undergoing proper acceleration, while the building (and air) would accelerate up past me because the Earth’s surface is accelerating outward (and eventually smacks into me).

But if I were further out in space, then I struggle to get which concept would have the most effect.  Is the Earth’s surface accelerating at me from a very long way away, or does that have little effect until I am closer?  Or are both concepts equally at work, as they appear to be when I am on the surface of the Earth?  Or are these metaphors that get too stretched when taken too far (whatever that is)?

Comment: The earth is not "accelerating towards you" when you stand on it, rather it is "blocking your geodesic motion".  I won't say more as this alone might help you to reconcile the two "concepts".

Comment: @m4r35n357 If I am on an inertial, constant speed geodesic curved towards the centre of the Earth, where does the acceleration with respect to Earth come from if not from the Earth?

Comment: I am deliberately trying to avoid mentioning "acceleration", so asking me about it again is not going to help.  That was my one shot, I don't have any more words, perhaps others can help.

Comment: I am not sure why. If you drop off a mountain the mountain will definitely accelerate passed you as you free fall.  Or if you are on the Earth’s surface and a well suddenly opens up below you, you will free fall with no proper acceleration, while the well’s walls accelerate passed you.  The don’t go passed at a constant speed.

Comment: Is it because the geodesic is curved and so acceleration is happening but with a constant speed as far as the free falling object is concerned, but with respect to the Earth it appears as a change in speed?

Comment: Fay Dowker, professor of theoretical physics at Imperial College, London, also says everything is accelerating upwards (circa minute 8). https://youtu.be/IyBGWd6IddU

Comment: "Appeals to authority" are all very well, but this is a matter of interpretation.  Where she says the earth is accelerating upwards, I say it is pushing upwards, as if a rocket were supporting a platform against its geodesic motion.  I say force, she says acceleration, the difference is a factor.  We both agree that in free fall there is neither force nor acceleration.  However, her explanation is confusing you, whereas mine is clear (to me).  Anyway, I am not going to try any more to "do physics" in words, so you need to come up with a diagram and numbers if you want to provoke me further.

Comment: BTW I do not have a degree in physics, I just do this in my free time.

Comment: I raised this because you categorically said the Earth is not accelerating upwards, whereas she says without any ambiguity that it is.  I found her explanation very clear.  I found yours clear with regard to the Earth blocking geodesic motion, but it didn't explain the change of speed that can readily be seen between a free falling object and the Earth.  Also, if there is pushing, that implies a force and a force implies acceleration.  I just seek answers that resolve my query and to me words seem quite a reasonable way of learning (physics would have been a lot harder to learn without them).

Answer (score 0):

In GR observers that interact only with gravity are free falling. The presence of the gravitational field results in bending of geodesics in space-time. Both in space and in time. There is no natural way to separate space and time in GR. Curving in space is something along the lines of your second concept, while curving in time is rather along the lines of the first one. But, as I've said, these things cannot be naturally separated from each other. Another thing is that using these common analogies is often misleading. You should rather go into the formalism and see how things actually work. Trying to rephrase them in common terms is often difficult and the result is inaccurate as oftentimes they do not have close everyday life counterparts.